# type of map() and filter() operations of Optional

Tags: java, java-stream, lazy-evaluation, eager

Are the `map()` and `filter()` of `Optional` are lazy like `Stream`?

How can I confirm their type?

Comment: You *could* easily verify that by logging something in the map or filter expression and then check at what time the stuff is logged.

Comment: A line of code would be more helpful :)

Comment: No, most helpful would be for you to figure out on your own, that way you learn the most.

Comment: @MehrajMalik my answer was terrible (beyond that it was plain wrong), please accept the other one that you have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference between a `Stream` and an `Optional`.

A `Stream` encapsulates an entire processing pipeline, gathering all operations before doing anything. This allows the implementation to pick up different processing strategies, depending on what result is actually requested. This also allows to insert modifiers like `unordered()` or `parallel()` into the chain, as at this point, nothing has been done so far, so we can alter the behavior of the subsequent actual processing.

An extreme example is `Stream.of(1, 2, 3).map(function).count()`, which will not process `function` at all in Java 9, as the invariant result of `3` can be determined without.

In contrast, an `Optional` is just a wrapper around a value (if not empty). Each operation will be performed immediately, to return either, a new `Optional` encapsulating the new value or an empty `Optional`. In Java 8, all methods returning an `Optional`, i.e.`map`, `flatMap` or `filter`, will just return an empty optional when being applied to an empty optional, so when chaining them, the empty optional becomes a kind of dead-end.

But Java 9 will introduce `Optional<T> or​(Supplier<? extends Optional<? extends T>>)`, which may return a non-empty optional from the supplier when being applied to an empty optional.

Since an `Optional` represents a (possibly absent) value, rather than a processing pipeline, you can query the same `Optional` as many times you want, whether the query returns a new `Optional` or a final value.

It’s easy to verify. The following code

```
Optional<String> first=Optional.of("abc");
Optional<String> second=first.map(s -> {
    System.out.println("Running map");
    return s + "def";
});
System.out.println("starting queries");
System.out.println("first: "+(first.isPresent()? "has value": "is empty"));
System.out.println("second: "+(second.isPresent()? "has value": "is empty"));
second.map("second's value: "::concat).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

will print

```
Running map
starting queries
first: has value
second: has value
second's value: abcdef
```

demonstrating that the mapping function is evaluated immediately, before any other query, and that we still can query the `first` optional after we created a second via `map` and query optionals multiple times.

In fact, it is *strongly recommended* to check via `isPresent()` first, before calling `get()`.

There is no equivalent stream code, as re-using `Stream` instances this way is invalid. But we can show that intermediate operations are not performed before the terminal operation has been commenced:

```
Stream<String> stream=Stream.of("abc").map(s -> {
    System.out.println("Running map");
    return s + "def";
});
System.out.println("starting query");
Optional<String> result = stream.findAny();
System.out.println("result "+(result.isPresent()? "has value": "is empty"));
result.map("result value: "::concat).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

will print

```
starting query
Running map
result has value
result value: abcdef
```

showing that the mapping function is not evaluated before the terminal operation `findAny()` starts. Since we can’t query a stream multiple times, `findAny()` even uses `Optional` as return value, which allows us to do that with the final result.

---

There are other semantic differences between the operations of the same name, e.g. `Optional.map` will return an empty `Optional` if the mapping function evaluates to `null`. For a stream, it makes no difference whether the function passed to `map` returns `null` or a non-`null` value (that’s why we can count the elements without knowing whether it does).

Answer (score 5):

```
 String r = Optional.of("abc")
            .map(s -> {
                System.out.println("Running map");
                return s + "def";
            })
            .filter(s -> {
                System.out.println("First Filter");
                return s.equals("abcdef");
            })
            .map(s -> {
                System.out.println("mapping");
                return s + "jkl";
            })
            .orElse("done");

    System.out.println(r);
```

Running this will produce:

> Running map,  First Filter,  mapping  abcdefjkl

On the other hand running this:

```
String r = Optional.of("mnt") //changed
            .map(s -> {
                System.out.println("Running map");
                return s + "def";
            })
            .filter(s -> {
                System.out.println("First Filter");
                return s.equals("abcdef");
            })
            .map(s -> {
                System.out.println("mapping");
                return s + "jkl";
            })
            .orElse("done");
```

> Running map,  First Filter, done

I always thought that since the `map` is only execute based on the previous `filter`, this would be considered `lazy`. It turns out this is *not true*:

```
 Optional.of("s").map(String::toUpperCase)
 Stream.of("test").map(String::toUpperCase)
```

The `map` from `Optional` will get executed; while the one from `Stream` will not.

**EDIT**

go and up-vote the other answer here. This is edited because of the other one.

Comment: Three days without objections… all you have proven, is, that an empty `Optional` does not evaluate the mapping function. Which does not need to be thought “the stream-way”. Think of a `HashSet`…after you removed all elements, methods processing all elements become no-ops.  It doesn’t prove whether these operations are eager or lazy. Which is best illustrated by the fact that `Optional` operations are *not lazy*…

Comment: @Holger I had a hint I'm missing something, thx for getting back here. I always thought that `filter.filter` on an Optional would count as lazy, because the second filter is not evaluated based on the first.

Comment: @Holger re-read the question and the answer. I'm an idiot, thx for proving me very wrong.